# Creating an optimistic response for a reordered connection

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

What is the best way to 'reorder' a connection in RelayJS?

In my user interface, I allow my user to 'swap' two items, but creating a mutation around that is a bit tricky.

What I'm doing right now is the naive way, namely using `FIELDS_CHANGE` to change my node itself.

It works, but the problem is I can't seem to write an optimistic update for it. I am able to just pass a list of ids to my graphql server, but that doesn't work for the optimistic update because it expects the actual data.

So I guess I have to mock out my 'connection' interface, but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I 'copied' my reordered nodes to getOptimisticResponse but it seems to be ignored. The data matches the actual server response. (ids simplified)

original:

```
{
  item: {
    edges: {
      {cursor: 1, node: {id:2}}
      {cursor: 2, node: {id:1}}
    }
  }
}
```

(doesn't do anything):
optimistic reponse:

```
{
  item: {
    edges: {
      node: {id:1}
      node: {id:2}
    }
  }
}
```

server reponse:

```
{
  item: {
    edges: {
      {cursor: 1, node: {id:1}}
      {cursor: 2, node: {id:2}}
    }
  }
}
```

What gives? It's equivalent (except for the cursor), and even if I add the cursor in, it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Also is there an easier way to do mock my ids to a connection?

Also, as an aside, is there a way to get this data piecemeal? Right now, reordering two item re-requests the whole list because of my mutation config. I suppose I can do it with `RANGE_ADD`, and `RANGE_DELETE` to 'simulate a swap` but is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you trigger a mutation in response to the user reordering the items, I assume, you store the position or order of the items on the server side. For what you're doing, one way of creating optimistic response can be using that `position` or `order` information. On the server side, an item needs to provide an additional field `position`. On the client side, the items displayed are sorted by `position`.

When the user swaps two items, in the optimistic response of your client-side mutation, you just need to swap the `position` fields of those two items. The same applies on the server-side mutation.

The optimistic response code can be like:

```
getOptimisticResponse() {
  return {
    item1: {
      id: this.props.item1.id,
      position: this.props.item2.position,
    },
    item2: {
      id: this.props.item2.id,
      position: this.props.item1.position,
    },
  };
}
```